# How to run gauss markov mobility model on ns3 simulator?

Tags: ns-3

I am an absolute bigger in NS3 and also on stackoverflow. How do I run the gauss markov mobility model?

The command that I have in the terminal window is:    ~/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31$ ./waf --run src/mobility/model/gauss-markov-mobility-model

But somehow model is not found. I'm sure that I've keyed in the right folder locations and filename. For the examples folder, it is totally fine.

Can anybody provide guidance? I am unable to post pics as a new user. [image: command I use]

[image: file location]

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs [Gauss Markov Mobility Model](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_gauss_markov_mobility_model.html)

```cpp
MobilityHelper mobility;
mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::GaussMarkovMobilityModel",
  "Bounds", BoxValue (Box (0, 150000, 0, 150000, 0, 10000)),
  "TimeStep", TimeValue (Seconds (0.5)),
  "Alpha", DoubleValue (0.85),
  "MeanVelocity", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=800|Max=1200]"),
  "MeanDirection", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=6.283185307]"),
  "MeanPitch", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.05|Max=0.05]"),
  "NormalVelocity", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.0|Bound=0.0]"),
  "NormalDirection", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.2|Bound=0.4]"),
  "NormalPitch", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.02|Bound=0.04]"));
mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::RandomBoxPositionAllocator",
  "X", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=150000]"),
  "Y", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=150000]"),
  "Z", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=10000]"));
mobility.Install (wifiStaNodes);
```